# split string into array with a common regx

Tags: swift, string

In Swift I have a string like:

```
let str = "5~895893799,,6~898593679,,7~895893679,,8~895893799,,5~895893799,,6~898593679,,7~895893679,,8~895893799";
```

From this I need to get only the number which is before "~" which is [5,6,7,8,5,6,7,8]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: actual string is "5~895893799,,6~898593679,,7~895893679,,8~895893799,,5~895893799,,6~898593679,,7~895893679,,8~895893799"

Comment: Please post a snippet of code which is your best guess to solve this problem and ask for help to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of `components(separatedBy:)` and `compactMap`.

```
let str = "5~895893799,,6~898593679,,7~895893679,,8~895893799,,5~895893799,,6~898593679,,7~895893679,,8~895893799"
let nums = str.components(separatedBy: ",,")
              .compactMap { $0.components(separatedBy: "~").first }
```

That gives the string array:

> ["5", "6", "7", "8", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

If you want an array of Int, add:

```
.compactMap { Int($0) }
```

to the end.

```
let nums = str.components(separatedBy: ",,")
              .compactMap { $0.components(separatedBy: "~").first }
              .compactMap { Int($0) }
```

That gives:

> [5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Answer (score 0):

You could define this regular expression:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"\d+(?=~)"#)
```

- `\d` : matches any digit
- `+` : this is the one or more quantifier
- `(?=~)` : Positive lookahead for *"~"*

and use it like so:

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: (str as NSString).length)
let matches = regex.matches(in: str, range: range)

let strings: [String] = matches.map { match in
    let subRange = match.range
    let startIndex = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: subRange.lowerBound)
    let endIndex = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: subRange.upperBound)
    let subString = String(str[startIndex..<endIndex])

    return subString
}

let numbers = strings.compactMap(Int.init)  //[5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```